# Search for file and send result as attachment

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I have a command that list a specific file name, with a specific extension(.csv) and on the current day(m-d-y) as the variable "first". This is a file that is created everyday in my directory and it works.

```
first=$(ls -l --time-style=+'%m-%d-%Y' example_daily_Report_*.csv| awk -v d=$(date +%m-%d-%Y) '$6==d')
```

I am trying to email that file when it is listed, and not the command output. How would I do that? Below is my attempt

```
echo "$first"|  mail -s 'test' test@website.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `xargs` command to pass the attachment as an argument. 
try to do the following:

```
echo "$first"|  xargs mail -s 'test' test@website.com -A
```